# How to pass array list data to a fragment from main activity when using bottom navigation view and Android Navigation component?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to pass array list data to one of my fragments in the nav bar from main activity. Is there a simple way to implement this? Or should I use activity instead of the fragment? I need to pass the array list data to my HomeFragment and use recycler view adapter in the fragment, but now the issue is I don't know how to pass data because I am using bottom navigation view and Android Navigation component.

Main Activity

```
package com.example.a5t1v2

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.GridView
import androidx.navigation.NavArgument
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var shoppingItemList:MutableList<Item>
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        initUI()

        val dbHelper = DBHelper(this)
        populateDB(dbHelper)
        shoppingItemList = dbHelper.getAlItems()

    }


    private fun populateDB(dbHelper: DBHelper) {
        dbHelper.insertItem(Item("Bread",1,"Default", urgent = true, bought = false,null))
        dbHelper.insertItem(Item("Chocolate Bar",1,"Small", urgent = false, bought = false,null))
        dbHelper.insertItem(Item("Instant noodle",1,"Default", urgent = false, bought = false,null))
        dbHelper.insertItem(Item("Juice",2,"Large", urgent = false, bought = false,null))
        dbHelper.insertItem(Item("Milk",3,"Large", urgent = true, bought = false,null))

        dbHelper.insertItem(Item("Shampoo",1,"Small", urgent = false, bought = true,"24 Aug 2020"))
        dbHelper.insertItem(Item("Shower Gel",1,"Large", urgent = false, bought = true,"24 Aug 2020"))
    }

    private fun initUI() {
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.urgentListFragment, R.id.homeFragment, R.id.completedListFragment))
        bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottomNavigationView)
        navController = findNavController(R.id.fragmentContainerView)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController,appBarConfiguration)
        bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }
}
```

Comment: The best way these days is to use a ``ViewModel``: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel You basically get a component that an activity and its fragments all share, then something (like the activity) can update the data in the VM, and when the fragment observes that data in the VM it'll see the current value, and get any updates pushed to it, and then you can display that data. You could talk to the fragment directly by finding it in the ``supportFragmentManager`` but view models take care of a lot of the complications, and they're recommended for modern apps

Answer (score 0):

An easy and good way would be to use a `sharedViewModel`.

Create a `ViewModel` and declare a `LiveData` in it.

```
class MainViewModel: ViewModel () {
    private val arrayListLiveData = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Item>>()

}
```

Inside `Activity`, create an `instance` of this `ViewModel` in the acitivity, and you can send your `arrayList` from here using `post` on the `liveData`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mainViewModel: MainViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        
        mainViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
        
        mainViewModel.arrayListLiveData.post(YOUR_ARRAY_LIST_DATA)
    }
}
```

You can observe the same `liveData` inside the `fragment`, and would receive the posted `arrayList` there, from the `Activity`

```
class TestFragment : Fragment(R.layout.test) {

    private lateinit var mainViewModel: MainViewModel

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        mainViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

        mainViewModel.arrayListLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { arrayList ->
            //Perform desired operation with the array list
        }
    }

}
```